# Dominated convergence theorem for singular function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Suppose I have a family of integrable function $f_a$ such that $\int_\Omega f_a <M$ and this $M$ is independent of $a$. And $f_a$ is smooth in $\Omega$ but $f_a|_{\partial \Omega}=\infty$ for all $a$. Also , $f_a$ ia locally uniform bounded and $f_a$ converges to $f_b$ pointwisely in any compact subset of $\Omega$. Could I conclude that $$\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow b}\int_\Omega f_a=\int_\Omega f_b$$

Comment: No. Take $\Omega=(-1,1)$, $f_n=0$ on $|x|<1-1/n$ and arrange matters so that $\int f_n=1$ for all $n$.